# Interface Builder Plugin Image inspector property problem on load

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsimage, ibplugin

i have created a custom NSView that displays an image.
i have created a property in Inspector view with binding to File's Owner.

Everything works fine in runtime image changing.
But nothing is loaded when i save and load xib file.

here is the simplified code:

```
IBDocument *document = [IBDocument documentForObject:self];
[self->defaultImage release];
self->defaultImage = [document documentImageNamed:aImage];
[self->defaultImage setName:aImage];
[self->defaultImage retain];
```

The `[document documentImageNamed:aImage]` returns an NSImage in runtime, but when loading from file it return `nil`

though the NSImageWell works fine in runtime and when initialized from coder.

What i'm missing?

Thans.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement NSCoding protocol for you custom object. 
  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html